# When does a prepositional phrase modify a subject vs a linking verb?

Tags: subjects, prepositional-phrases, linking-verbs

The bold words are the words being modified by the prepositional phrase.

According to englishgrammar101.com:

The crystal **glassware** is from Carlsbad.    (Is this a subject complement?)

Jessie's new apartment **is** on the third floor.     (Is this a state-of-being?)

Comment: Is this a homework question?  Can you share your reasoning, and point to where you are stuck, and what's confusing you?

Comment: @aparente001 It's not a homework question. I don't understand why the prepositional phrase in the first question is modifying the subject while the prepositional phrase in the second question is modifying the verb.

Comment: The PP "from Carlsbad" is not a modifier, but a locative complement of the verb "is". Locative complements are not predicative, so it's not a subject complement, though it does of course refer to the subject.  Similarly, in your 2nd example, the PP "on the third floor" is not a modifier but a locative complement of "is". Again, it refers to the subject.

Comment: @BillJ So the website is wrong to claim that the bolded words are being modified?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. The PPs "from Carlsbad" and "on the third floor" are complements of the verb "is", not modifiers at all, though they do of course refer to the subjects. Incidentally, subject complements are either noun phrases or adjective phrases, e.g. "Ed is **a teacher**" / "Kim is **very pretty**".

Comment: @BillJ That would explain my confusion. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @BillJ - How about moving your helpful explanations to an answer? // MisterAyy, your clarifying comments were helpful.  How about editing your question to include the clarifications?